# FlashPunk + Flashdevelop - How to use sponsor provided preloader

Tags: flash, actionscript, flashdevelop

I have developed a flash game using FlashPunk (on FlashDevelop). And now that I am trying to add a sponsor preloader and splashscreen to my game, I realize the flashpunk forums are down, and have been for over a week now :( Speak of bad timing.

I imagine some of you here do use FlashPunk. How have you managed to add such sponsor stuff to your game? I haven't had to deal with swf and fla at all until now.

The sponsor's preloader is an actual loading bar, at the end of which it also plays an animated splash screen.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the "sponsor" have it's own api to work with? As in you interface your AS3 code with the stuff you use to make your sponsors work?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the exact same problem when i tried to add sponsorship SWF's to my game projects (I'm using FlashDevelop & flixel/as3). After a long search i found a way of adding the SWF, through converting it into some byteArray or something and adding to the stage. It worked (checked with Kongregate loader), but the clip just kept on looping and i found no way of accessing which frame its playing or how to stop it.

I'v integrated animations from swfs (which are created in flash, but are converted symbols), so i guess the easiest way to do this is to give the FLA file to someone who has FLASH IDE, convert the whole animation into a symbol(movieclip) and Embed the symbol & instantiate it as movieclip and add to the stage and finally check its **currentFrame**.

```
[Embed(source = "../lib/Sponsor.swf", symbol = "SponsorAnim")]
private var Sponsor:Class;
private var SponsorAnim:MovieClip = new Sponsor();
```

Hope my experience might help you.

Comment: I'd like to add that since the question involved a preloader, this should be added in the Preloader class of your project. You can then interact with the converted movieclip's preloading bars and finally play the splash screen once everything's finished.